# how can i select a specific string in RegExp From the middle

Tags: regex

i have this String: "abcdef; abcdef"

i need select this part:

"; abcdef"

like :

"abcdef`; abcdef`"

**i need start from this ; to end the String**

Comment: Use this regex, `;\s+\w+` What language you are using?

Comment: i need online https://www.regexpal.com code i use javascript

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi Kumar Rajwanshi thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- input string: "abcdef; abcdef"
- desired value: "abcdef ; abcdef"
- if you need only the 2nd part, just put $2 on subst const

Code:

```
const regex = /(.*)(;\s\w+)/gm;
const str = `abcdef; abcdef`;
const subst = `$1 $2`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

example:
https://regex101.com/r/w9pvUn/3